# Spring Integration with SFTP

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I'm building a little microservice to access files from a SFTP file server. I decided to use Spring Integration SFTP to get the job done. I'm new to Spring Integration and confused with how it all works.

My goal is to get a list of files a directory on a SFTP server and present them to the user interface. From there a user will select a file for download and I'll use the filename to stream the file from the SFTP server to the user interface.

I'm using the following code which does work.

```
Entire class to handle SFTP with SSH


@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class SftpConfig {
    @Value("${sftp.host}")
    private String sftpHost;
    @Value("${sftp.port:22}")
    private int sftpPort;
    @Value("${sftp.user}")
    private String sftpUser;
    @Value("${sftp.privateKey:#{null}}")
    private Resource sftpPrivateKey;
    @Value("${sftp.privateKeyPassphrase:}")
    private String sftpPrivateKeyPassphrase;
    @Value("${sftp.password:#{null}}")
    private String sftpPasword;
    @Value("${sftp.remote.directory:/}")
    private String sftpRemoteDirectory;

    @Bean
public SessionFactory<LsEntry> sftpSessionFactory() {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost(sftpHost);
        factory.setPort(sftpPort);
        factory.setUser(sftpUser);
        if (sftpPrivateKey != null) {
            factory.setPrivateKey(sftpPrivateKey);
            factory.setPrivateKeyPassphrase(sftpPrivateKeyPassphrase);
        } else {
            factory.setPassword(sftpPasword);
        }
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpLS")
    @Bean
public SftpOutboundGateway getFtpLS() {
        SftpOutboundGateway gateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "ls", "'" + sftpRemoteDirectory + "' + payload");
        gateway.setOption(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.NAME_ONLY);
        return gateway;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpGet")
    @Bean
public SftpOutboundGateway getFtpGet() {
        SftpOutboundGateway gateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "get", "'" + sftpRemoteDirectory + "' + payload");
        gateway.setOption(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.STREAM);
        return gateway;
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "ftpLS")
    public interface FtpLS {
        List list(String directory);
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "ftpGet")
    public interface FtpGet {
        InputStream get(String fileName);
    }

}
```

Run

```
@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner(SftpConfig.FtpLS ftpLS, SftpConfig.FtpGet ftpGet) {
    return args -> {
        List<String> list = ftpLS.list("139");
        System.out.println("Result:" + list);

        InputStream is = ftpGet.get("139/" + list.get(0));
        String theString = IOUtils.toString(is,"UTF-8");
        System.out.println("Result:" + theString);

    };
}
```

My number one question is this the correct approach?

Secondly, do I need two interfaces in order to use the two different SftpOutboundGateway's?

Lastly, is there a better way to pass in a dynamic directory name when doing a FtsGet? Right now I'm passing I'm concatenating 139 with the base directory in a string and passing it in through the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this the correct approach?

Yes, the approach is correct. Although I would suggest do not use `isSharedSession` for the gateway since it might be used from different threads by different users.

> do I need two interfaces?

No, you really can have one `@MessagingGateway`, but with several methods marked with their own `@Gateway` annotations.

> is there a better way to pass in a dynamic directory?

No, your approach is correct. There is no something like `working directory` to switch automatically, like we can do in FTP.

Comment: So by not sharing the FTP session, a new session will be created with every request right?

Comment: Correct, but that is the way do not share `InputStream` in between different requests. More over a read is blocking in one session. You can't have another in parallel until you don't close the current one. You may consider to use a `CachingSessionFactory` wrapper, but still not sharing target session.